# UnitOfWork + Repository pattern - Adding a custom repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I'm following [this example](https://medium.com/@utterbbq/c-unitofwork-and-repository-pattern-305cd8ecfa7a) :

**Entities**

```
[Table("Authors")]
public class Author {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
[Table("Books")]
public class Book {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Author_ID { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Author_ID")] 
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

**Generic repository**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   IQueryable<T> Entities { get; }
   void Remove(T entity);
   void Add(T entity);
}
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    private IDbSet<T> _dbSet => _dbContext.Set<T>();
    public IQueryable<T> Entities => _dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Author> AuthorRepository { get; }
    IRepository<Book> BookRepository { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Commits all changes
    /// </summary>
    void Commit();
    /// <summary>
    /// Discards all changes that has not been commited
    /// </summary>
    void RejectChanges();
    void Dispose();
}
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    #region Repositories
    public IRepository<Author> AuthorRepository => 
       new GenericRepository<Author>(_dbContext);
    public IRepository<Book> BookRepository => 
       new GenericRepository<Book>(_dbContext);
    #endregion
    public UnitOfWork(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
    public void RejectChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
              .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    entry.Reload();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

What if I need a custom Add function?
If I add a  Code property in my Book class :

```
[Table("Books")]
public class Book {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Author_ID { get; set; } 
    public string Code { get; set; } //I'm adding a Code property here

    [ForeignKey("Author_ID")] 
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to autofill the Code property before insert the Book object in DB.
I guess I need to create a "custom" **BookRepository** which inherit the **GenericRepository** and override the **Add function** in order to have something like that :

```
public void Add(Book entity)
    {
        entity.Code = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds+entity.Title.Replace(" ","");
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

I'm not familiar with design pattern / inheritance / interface concepts. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: I have a question for you, what's the benefit you think you have behind the pattern you are attempting to follow? I see all those classes when I could just do `context.SomeTable.Add` and I seriously doubt what makes people attempt (and fail to do so) to hide EF through a UoW/Repository. Do notice that you are leaking the EF dependency to the client, so the "to be able to change EF" does not even apply here

Comment: I will work on a project which use the Uow/Repository pattern.. I didn't choose it myself. I'm training to use it.

Comment: I think you should become familiar with those concepts before attempting something like this since you're using them. That said, there's nothing stopping you from making the book repo however you want it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I fully agree with you, but this is question for people writing all these blogs and (simplified naïve) "examples".

Comment: Whatever special treatment of entities is required, do it in a class named <prefix>Service. Repositories are unaware of business logic (which this is about), services are. But all this is opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic that you are trying to add **belongs the Model and not the Repository**, repository has nothing to do with it. Repositories responsible is to access database and run queries against it.

I have written an article how you plan Thin repository and unit of work using EF

I'll insert the link below
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1157241/Very-Thin-Database-Layer-using-UnitOfWork-Pattern

Hope this helps